# How to change all columns in csv file to str?

Tags: python, pandas

I am working on a script that imports an excel file, iterates through a column called "Title," and returns False if a certain keyword is present in "Title." The script runs, until I get to part where I want to export another csv file that gives me a separate column. My error is as follows: `AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'lower'`

Based on this error, I changed the df.Title to a string using `df['Title'].astype(str)`, but I get the same error.

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_excel(r'C:/Users/Downloads/61_MONDAY_PROCESS_9.16.19.xlsx')
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Date Added','Track Item', 'Retailer Item ID','UPC','Title','Manufacturer','Brand','Client Product 
Group','Category','Subcategory',
                           'Amazon Sub Category','Segment','Platform'])
df['Title'].astype(str)
df['Retailer Item ID'].astype(str)

excludes = ['chainsaw','pail','leaf blower','HYOUJIN','brush','dryer','genie','Genuine 
Joe','backpack','curling iron','dog','cat','wig','animal','dryer',':','tea', 'Adidas', 'Fila',
'Reebok','Puma','Nike','basket','extension','extensions','batteries','battery','[EXPLICIT]']

my_excludes = [set(x.lower().split()) for x in excludes]
match_titles = [e for e in df.Title.astype(str) if any(keywords.issubset(e.lower().split()) for 
keywords in my_excludes)]

def is_match(title, excludes = my_excludes):
    if any(keywords.issubset(title.lower().split()) for keywords in my_excludes):
        return True
    return False
```

This is the part that returns the error:

```
df['match_titles'] = df['Title'].apply(is_match)
result = df[df['match_titles']]['Retailer Item ID']
print(df)
df.to_csv('Asin_List(9.18.19).csv',index=False)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the following code to import your file:

```
data = pd.read_excel(r'C:/Users/Downloads/61_MONDAY_PROCESS_9.16.19.xlsx',
                      dtype='str')`
```

Comment: Thank you. The code runs, but I still get the same error: AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'lower' even after specifying every column is a str

Comment: What you might be looking for is `my_excludes = [set(str.lower(x).split()) for x in excludes]`. Does that work?

Answer (score 0):

For pandas.read_excel, you can pass an optional parameter dtype.

You can also use it to pass multiple data types for different columns:

ex: `dtype={'Retailer Item ID': int, 'Title': str})`

Comment: @Palmer_Eldrich. If this response was helpful, would you mind upvoting it? I'm new here and it would help me a lot. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

At the line where you wrote

```
match_titles = [e for e in df.Title.astype(str) if any(keywords.issubset(e.lower().split()) for 
keywords in my_excludes)]
```

python returns as variable e an integer and not the String you like.This happens because when you write `df.Title.astype(str)` you are searching the index of a new pandas dataframe containing only the column Title and not the contents of the column.If you want to iterate through column you should try

```
match_titles = [e for e in df.ix[:,5] if any(keywords.issubset(e.lower().split()) for keywords in my_excludes)
```

The df.ix[:,5] returns the fifth column of the dataframe df,which is the column you want.If this doesn't work try with the `iteritems()` function.
The main idea is that if you directly assign a df[column] to something else,you are assigning its index,not its contents.